# hibernate-ogm-ignite-5.3.1.Final start ignite failed. Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive

Tags: java, hibernate, ignite

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: igniteWithJpa] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at com.ignite.jpa.MainIgnite_jpa.StartApp.main(StartApp.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: OGM001709: Unable initialize cache 'Department'
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.ignite.impl.IgniteCacheInitializer.initializeEntities(IgniteCacheInitializer.java:85)
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.ignite.impl.IgniteCacheInitializer.initializeSchema(IgniteCacheInitializer.java:63)
at org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.SchemaDefiningObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(SchemaDefiningObserver.java:42)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:374)
at org.hibernate.ogm.boot.impl.OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:55)
at org.hibernate.ogm.boot.impl.OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:23)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
... 5 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.active(true).
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.checkClusterState(IgniteKernal.java:3749)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.cache(IgniteKernal.java:2746)
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.ignite.impl.IgniteDatastoreProvider.getCache(IgniteDatastoreProvider.java:105)
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.ignite.impl.IgniteDatastoreProvider.getEntityCache(IgniteDatastoreProvider.java:99)
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.ignite.impl.IgniteCacheInitializer.initializeEntities(IgniteCacheInitializer.java:76)
... 12 more

Comment: what's the question? I can see only a stack trace without formatting. Could you please read the article. Briefly: ask a question, show personal research effort, format the question properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.